Call Rest API from Webhook
Our ticket system has a REST api and I wish to create a new ticket when a chat is completed in RocketChat. RocketChat can call webhooks.
How can I get the two to talk together? Is Zapier the only way?
Ideally I'd like something on the local LAN, as opposed to an external service like Zapier.
Is there an OpenSource solution that can receive a webhook and then call call the REST api?

There are at least 2 options:

Coding based -> Create simple node.js app that will consume RocketChat webook and call your ticket system API.
No-code -> Use n8n automation software which works just like zapier but it can be launched locally. Install and configure it to use webooks or just RocketChat integration endpoint along with HTTP request to your ticket system.


So I am on the right track. I need a system (n8n) to receive the web hook, convert it and send out the REST api call?

Yes.. Your demand was to run that integration locally so you need create own software... or simply use "of the shelf" automation software. In that case I've suggested n8n...
